# elements of a group with limits

Tags: coq

I want to define minimum and maximum of group by following code, but it has a problem. Plz guide me.

```
Definition groupmin (sn maxlimit maxsn: nat) : nat := 
   let avg := div maxlimit maxsn in 
   (sn*avg) - (avg - 1).

 Definition groupmax (sn maxlimit maxsn: nat) : nat := 
   let avg := div maxlimit maxsn in sn*avg.
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what you are asking, and even what you are trying to accomplish. Please try to explain some more, and perhaps someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are assuming that there exists such a thing as a `div` function.  In bare Coq, with no library loaded, no such function exists.

To have a function that looks like natural number division, I suggest you load the `Arith` library.  Then you will be allowed to use the notation `a / b` for division.

Here is an example:

```
Require Import Arith.
Check (fun x y => x / y).
(* this returns : fun x y : nat => x / y : nat -> nat -> nat *)
Compute (12 / 5).
(* this returns : = 2 : nat *)
Locate "_ / _".
(* this returns : "x / y" := Nat.div x y : nat_scope *)
```

I still don't understand what you mean by minimum and maximum of a group, but at least  you should be able to write some Coq code that will be accepted by the system.